# Why is LogStash not creating separate columns for IIS logs in elasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, iis, logstash, iis-7.5, logstash-configuration

Our IIS server generates logs in the following format : -

```
Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

2018-09-13 08:47:52 ::1 GET / - 80 U:papl ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/68.0.3440.106+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 453
2018-09-13 08:47:52 ::1 GET /api/captcha.aspx rnd=R43YM 80 U:papl ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/68.0.3440.106+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/ 200 0 0 36
```

Now I want to config logstash in such a way where it can create separate columns for IP, RequestMethodType i.e. GET or POST, PageName which is here /api/captcha.aspx.

But it is creating a single column named "message" in elasticSearch and storing whole value in this message field.

So what changes should I make in logstash to create separate columns in ElasticSearch for IP, RequestMethod(POST/GET) and PageName?

Currently, I am using the following filter:-

```
match => {"message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration} %{URIPATH:uriStem} %{NOTSPACE:uriQuery} %{NUMBER:port} %{NOTSPACE:username} %{IPORHOST:clientIP} %{NOTSPACE:protocolVersion} %{NOTSPACE:userAgent} %{NOTSPACE:cookie} %{NOTSPACE:referer} %{NOTSPACE:requestHost} %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:subresponse} %{NUMBER:win32response} %{NUMBER:bytesSent} %{NUMBER:bytesReceived} %{NUMBER:timetaken}"
```

In this, it created only messages field and stores all the values in this single field.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

NB: to test your pattern, you can use [this site](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result), which allow to save a lot of time when working with patterns.

The pattern you're using is too long if you just want IP, request and pageName, you should just try to extract what you need. In addition to this, a shorter pattern will be quicker to execute and more resilient to change.

This filter correctly extract what you asked:

```
match => {"message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:PageName}"}
```

With this pattern and the logs you provided, you'd get this result (with the site I've linked above):

[image]

I tested the filter with logstash:

```
filter {
    grok { match => {"message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:PageName}"} }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json }
}
```

With this input:

> 2018-09-16 04:11:52 W3SVC10 webserver 107.6.166.194 GET /axestrack/homepagedata/ uname=satish34&pwd=3445&panelid=1 80 - 223.188.235.131 HTTP/1.1 Dalvik/1.6.0+(Linux;+U;+Android+4.4.4;+2014818+MIUI/V7.5.2.0.KHJMIDE) - - vehicletrack.biz 200 0 0 730 229 413

I'm getting this result:

```
{
   "client":"107.6.166.194",
   "method":"GET",
   "@version":"1",
   "host":"frsred-0077",
   "message":"2018-09-16 04:11:52 W3SVC10 webserver 107.6.166.194 GET /axestrack/homepagedata/ uname=satish34&pwd=3445&panelid=1 80 - 223.188.235.131 HTTP/1.1 Dalvik/1.6.0+(Linux;+U;+Android+4.4.4;+2014818+MIUI/V7.5.2.0.KHJMIDE) - - vehicletrack.biz 200 0 0 730 229 413\r",
   "@timestamp":"2018-09-18T08:13:23.539Z",
   "PageName":"/axestrack/homepagedata/"
}
```

Comment: What 'not working' means? Add any new info in the question, it'll be easier to read. Also put your full logstash configuration in your question, it might be useful for me to help you.